# Update Kodi (OSMC) video library using iOS remote

Tags: kodi, remote

I am running Kodi via OSMC on a Raspberry Pi 2. Is there a way to update the video library using the iOS Official Kodi remote? The [Kodi iOS remote wiki](http://kodi.wiki/view/Official_Kodi_Remote/iOS) is pretty vague.

If not are any other Kodi remotes that will do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same set up as you, I found if i changed the skin to the other default one (black and blue instead of the light blue), while more ugly is easier to navigate.

While on the TV show or Movies list press the left direction button and a menu will appear which contains the option, update library.

Also on the app, when on the remote control, press the cogs in the right corner and switch to gesture control. A held press will show more options for each items (which I couldn't figure out how to do on the normal remote).

Hope this helps!